# is there an open source asp.net server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, open-source

I'm currently looking for a lightweight alternative to Microsoft's IIS to run a small ASP.NET-based webservice.

Ultidev (http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/index.htm) have a very good - and free - solution. However, I would prefer an open source project. I have searched for a long time, but was not able to find anything.

Does anybody know a viable solution?

EDIT: thanks to all of you! somehow I have missed MONO's solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try XSP server which is build in C#.

http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET#ASP.NET_hosting_with_XSP

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the right solution for me. sorry for asking, sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees...

Answer (score 2):

This maybe of help to you. (open source solution for hosting .NET applications)

[Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I searched Google for "mono asp .net" and I found [this](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET).

> Mono has an implementation of ASP.NET 2.0, ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET AJAX.
>
> ...
>
> - Hosting on Apache servers.

Answer (score 1):

An open source ASP.NET server used in my project to host web services is [Cassini Web Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_Web_Server).